# What is the reason to add a browser driver as a maven dependency?

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, maven-dependency

Why to include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
     <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to the maven project if we still need to download the driver's binary?
What is the advantage?
What will happen if we change the version in dependency, but not download the new binary?

Answer (score 2):

The *Selenium Maven Artifacts* can be found in the [Central Maven Repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/). Now to start using any of the implementations in your Maven project, you just need to add the required dependency within your `pom.xml` (current release being *`Selenium v3.141.59`*):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

The diagram below shows the dependencies between the different *Selenium Maven Artifacts* as well as the most important *classes*/*interfaces* in those artifacts:

[image: Selenium_Maven_Dependencies]

If you know that you will only use a certain *WebDriver* implementation, e.g. the *FirefoxDriver*, you don't need to depend on the `selenium-java` artifact (which has a lot of transitive dependencies). Instead you can just add the `selenium-chrome-driver` dependency on the artifact you need.

Comment: Does it mean if you use `selenium-java` dependency, you do not need to add to the pom any `selenium-<browser>-driver`?

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, you are right. You should use the relevant dependency based on your requirements only.